# can't validate simple-captcha rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, captcha, simplecaptcha

I am running the simple-captcha gem in Rails to generate a captcha on user registration. Registration is handled by the Devise gem. I followed the instructions listed by the author here:

http://expressica.com/simple_captcha/

and the captcha displays on the form. However, the problem is that there is no check to see if the captcha is valid. I can register on the site and put anything I want in the captcha field (even if it doesn't match the captcha) and I can still continue. The author's installation instructions mention validation happens with the following method:

`@user.valid_with_captcha?`

However, I don't have a create action in my user controller since that is handled by Devise. How can I validate the captcha using the above method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `recaptcha` gem. Check out the wiki about [how to use it with Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise).